# Gráfico AmCharts com duas linhas e zoom

Tags: javascript, html, chartjs

Estou utilizando esse gráfico na minha página:

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "date": "2012-07-27",
  "value": 13
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-28",
  "value": 11
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-29",
  "value": 15
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-30",
  "value": 16
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-31",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-01",
  "value": 13
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-02",
  "value": 22
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-03",
  "value": 23
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-04",
  "value": 20
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-05",
  "value": 17
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-06",
  "value": 16
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-07",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-08",
  "value": 21
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-09",
  "value": 26
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-10",
  "value": 24
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-11",
  "value": 29
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-12",
  "value": 32
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-13",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-14",
  "value": 24
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-15",
  "value": 22
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-16",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-17",
  "value": 19
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-18",
  "value": 14
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-19",
  "value": 15
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-20",
  "value": 12
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-21",
  "value": 8
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-22",
  "value": 9
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-23",
  "value": 8
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-24",
  "value": 7
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-25",
  "value": 5
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-26",
  "value": 11
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-27",
  "value": 13
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-28",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-29",
  "value": 20
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-30",
  "value": 29
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-31",
  "value": 33
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-01",
  "value": 42
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-02",
  "value": 35
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-03",
  "value": 31
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-04",
  "value": 47
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-05",
  "value": 52
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-06",
  "value": 46
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-07",
  "value": 41
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-08",
  "value": 43
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-09",
  "value": 40
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-10",
  "value": 39
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-11",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-12",
  "value": 29
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-13",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-14",
  "value": 37
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-15",
  "value": 42
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-16",
  "value": 49
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-17",
  "value": 46
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-18",
  "value": 47
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-19",
  "value": 55
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-20",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-21",
  "value": 58
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-22",
  "value": 57
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-23",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-24",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-25",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-26",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-27",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-28",
  "value": 66
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-29",
  "value": 69
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-30",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-01",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-02",
  "value": 63
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-03",
  "value": 46
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-04",
  "value": 32
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-05",
  "value": 21
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-06",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-07",
  "value": 21
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-08",
  "value": 28
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-09",
  "value": 27
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-10",
  "value": 36
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-11",
  "value": 33
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-12",
  "value": 31
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-13",
  "value": 30
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-14",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-15",
  "value": 38
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-16",
  "value": 37
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-17",
  "value": 44
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-18",
  "value": 49
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-19",
  "value": 53
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-20",
  "value": 57
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-21",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-22",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-23",
  "value": 69
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-24",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-25",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-26",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-27",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-28",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-29",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-30",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-31",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-01",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-02",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-03",
  "value": 68
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-04",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-05",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-06",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-07",
  "value": 74
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-08",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-09",
  "value": 76
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-10",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-11",
  "value": 81
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-12",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-13",
  "value": 80
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-14",
  "value": 81
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-15",
  "value": 87
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-16",
  "value": 82
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-17",
  "value": 86
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-18",
  "value": 80
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-19",
  "value": 87
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-20",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-21",
  "value": 85
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-22",
  "value": 84
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-23",
  "value": 82
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-24",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-25",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-26",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-27",
  "value": 79
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-28",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-29",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-30",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-01",
  "value": 62
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-02",
  "value": 66
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-03",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-04",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-05",
  "value": 79
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-06",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-07",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-08",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-09",
  "value": 74
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-10",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-11",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-12",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-13",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-14",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-15",
  "value": 62
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-16",
  "value": 64
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-17",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-18",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-19",
  "value": 53
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-20",
  "value": 54
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-21",
  "value": 56
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-22",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-23",
  "value": 58
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-24",
  "value": 55
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-25",
  "value": 52
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-26",
  "value": 54
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-27",
  "value": 50
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-28",
  "value": 50
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-29",
  "value": 51
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-30",
  "value": 52
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-31",
  "value": 58
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-01",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-02",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-03",
  "value": 64
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-04",
  "value": 66
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-05",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-06",
  "value": 63
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-07",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-08",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-09",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-10",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-11",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-12",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-13",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-14",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-15",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-16",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-17",
  "value": 74
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-18",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-19",
  "value": 85
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-20",
  "value": 82
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-21",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-22",
  "value": 88
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-23",
  "value": 85
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-24",
  "value": 85
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-25",
  "value": 80
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-26",
  "value": 87
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-27",
  "value": 84
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-28",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-29",
  "value": 84
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-30",
  "value": 81
}];

// Set input format for the dates
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.tooltipText = "{value}"
series.strokeWidth = 2;
series.minBulletDistance = 15;

// Drop-shaped tooltips
series.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 20;
series.tooltip.background.strokeOpacity = 0;
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
series.tooltip.label.minWidth = 40;
series.tooltip.label.minHeight = 40;
series.tooltip.label.textAlign = "middle";
series.tooltip.label.textValign = "middle";

// Make bullets grow on hover
var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
bullet.circle.radius = 4;
bullet.circle.fill = am4core.color("#fff");

var bullethover = bullet.states.create("hover");
bullethover.properties.scale = 1.3;

// Make a panning cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.behavior = "panXY";
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series;

// Create vertical scrollbar and place it before the value axis
chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
chart.scrollbarY.parent = chart.leftAxesContainer;
chart.scrollbarY.toBack();

// Create a horizontal scrollbar with previe and place it underneath the date axis
chart.scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
chart.scrollbarX.series.push(series);
chart.scrollbarX.parent = chart.bottomAxesContainer;

chart.events.on("ready", function () {
  dateAxis.zoom({start:0.79, end:1});
});
```

```css
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!-- Styles -->


<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>


<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Porém ele só possui uma linha de dados. Gostaria de acrescentar uma outra, na cor vermelha, como faço?

OBS: O `AmCharts` possui outro template com duas ou mais linhas, porém ele não possui zoom.